# Fail routing HTTP Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-routing

I've this app-routing :

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductsComponent }      from './products.component';
import { ProductDetailComponent }  from './product-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'detail/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent },
    { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And I expect a URL like `localhost:25879/detail/id` but I've this kind of URL : 
`localhost:25879/detail/id?`. Why "?" in the Url ?

This is the call :

```
<div *ngIf="selectedProduct">

        <h2>

            {{selectedProduct.wording | uppercase}}
        </h2>
        <button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
    </div>
```

and the .ts file :

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

import { Product }                from './Product';
import { ProductService }         from './products.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-products',
    templateUrl: './products.component.html'
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    products: Product[];
    selectedProduct: Product;

    constructor(
        private productService: ProductService,
        private router: Router) { }

    gotoDetail(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedProduct.id]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I noticed there is apparently two calls. The first have this url `localhost:25789/detail/1` (short display of the form) and directly after a "callback" which applies a "?" to my URL like `localhost:25789/detail/1?`(display nothing). Perhaps it's a call from .net-core Controller ?

**EDIT 2** I make a step. I change the ApiController to a Classic Controller.
And now I've this behavior : First  `localhost:25879/detail/id`, immediatly after `localhost:25879/detail/id?` and Third a "callback" (which reloads the page) on my Controller with this URL : `localhost:25879/detail/id?` but it displays my detail form. I think It's not a normal behavior...